# Does the iPhone's SQLite implementation support the full SQLite 3 standard?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

Does the iPhone's SQLite implementation support the full SQLite 3 standard?  That is, is every function in the SQLite specification present and standard-compliant?

If not, can someone point me to a document which explains what the differences are?

Sorry if this is a repeat question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's full SQLite3.

FWIW, there is no SQLite "standard" other than the SQLite implementation itself, which is what Apple uses.

Comment: So the implementation on the iPhone is not something that Apple wrote itself?  I thought it was more like the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) where each platform had its own implementation. Huh.

Comment: As far as I know, Apple just downloads the source from the SQLite site and compiles it.  I don't think there are any alternative implementations.

Comment: You may be confusing SQLite, which is a product (albeit public domain) with SQL, which is a specification.  SQLite itself does not implement the entire SQL specification, but much of it.  It would be possible to build a custom version of SQLite and remove some of the functionality from the standard product but I've never hear of anyone doing that.

Comment: No, I wasn't confusing them, but I can see why you might have thought that based on what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it on Windows and on the iPhone, and yes, it's exactly the same thing.